# Css Hover Not Working After Adding Some Stuff Below It

Tags: html, css

Im just learned the css from w3 school and trying to make a css , and this is my problem , at first the hover is working but i don't know why after i put some stuff below it , the hover no longer working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Here You Put Code */
body {
background-image:url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CYQ5F9q6YlE/VIX6zgIg8EI/AAAAAAAAGwU/nkOudSDpI18/s1600/website-background-rough-surface.jpg");
}
div {
margin:30px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:65px;
}
NODDOS {
font-size:60px;
position:absolute;
border:2px solid black;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
padding:160px;
padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
width:65%;
font-weight:bold;
}
.abcdefg { 
font-size:30px;
}
DONOTHACKUS {
position:absolute;
margin:30px;
margin-top:310px;
margin-left:20px;
}
DONOTHACK {
font-size:20px;
color:black;
background:;
border:3px solid black;
padding:10px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #888888;
text-decoration:none;
}
DONOTHACK:hover {
position: relative; 
top: -1px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #888888;
}
DONOTHACK a.hahaha {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
DONOTHACK a.hahaha:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
DONOTHACK a.hahaha:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
DONOTHACK a.hahaha:active {
color:blue;
}
PLEASE {
position:absolute;
margin-top:400px;
margin-left:70px;
border:3px solid black;
padding:8px;
}
DONTHACK {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
position:relative;
}
JUSTRUN {
position:absolute;
padding-top:500px;
padding-left : 30px;
}
DONTDDOSTOO {
font-size:18px;
}
/*-------------------*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<NODDOS>English Lesson
<p class="abcdefg">Welcome To English Lesson !</p>
</NODDOS>
<DONOTHACKUS>
<DONOTHACK><a class="hahaha" href="#">Home</a></DONOTHACK>
<DONOTHACK><a class="hahaha" href="#">Tentang</a></DONOTHACK>
<DONOTHACK><a class="hahaha" href="#">Kerjakan Soal</a></DONOTHACK>
</DONOTHACKUS>
<PLEASE><DONTHACK>Siapa Kita ?</DONTHACK>
</PLEASE>
<JUSTRUN>
<DONTDDOSTOO>Kita adalah perkumpulan dari smp 13 semarang yang membuat website ini untuk melatih kemampuan siswa dalam berbahasa inggris melalui soal soal yang diberikan . </DONTDDOSTOO>
</JUSTRUN>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone know where is the problem ?

EDIT : the hover is in the menu like home , kerjakan soal

Comment: Yes...you're making up your own elements...that's not going to work well unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot make up your own html elements. You must use existing ones.

Comment: so can anybody tell me which element is good for ?

Comment: `a`, `span`, `div`, `p`, `li`...  and a large list of etc.

Comment: ok thanks now how to close this thread ? :\

Comment: `<div class="DONOTHACK">`

Comment: Well you could use custom elements, if you register them `document.registerElement()` but it's not as widely supported as you'd probably hope.

Comment: just delete your question

Comment: This is all just so weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make stuff like 'DONTHACK' a class or an id of an element rather than an actual element. Something like:

```
.DONTHACK {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:40px;
  position:relative;
}

<p class="DONTHACK">Siapa Kita</p>
```

You could also use `<a>`, `<span>` or `<div>`. Please look up some basic HTML tutorials.

Comment: ok thanks good answer wait 5 minutes for free reputation :) cant accept before 5 min

Comment: Cheers. Give it a tick then ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the basic tags of the html. You can make your own tags only into the XML not in HTML. So please use the tags like `<a>, <div>, <nav>` and etc.
And please use classes and ids in css, use class like .DONOTHACK and for id use #DONOTHACK.IF got confused about Web design and Development please tak a look of  for basic learning